# How do I embed full pdfs using ReStructured Text?

Tags: image, pdf, restructuredtext, pelican

How do I embed a pdf using reStructured Text? With the following directive, I only get the first page.

```
.. image:: /pdfs/cv.pdf
```

For context, I'm trying to do this in a Pelican based blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin for Pelican called [pdf-img](https://github.com/cmacmackin/pdf-img) description says:

> Searches for any  tags within your article for which the source is a PostScript, EPS, or PDF file. It will produce a PNG preview of the file and this PNG will be displayed as the image. This preview will also act as a link to the original file. If the PDF/PS/EPS file is a multi-page document, then only the first page will be used for the preview.

That explains why you get those results.

I could find no plugin that "embeds a PDF" (by which I assume you want to embed a PDF viewer within your Pelican blog that would display the entire PDF, allowing the viewer to scroll through it in an iframe or something like that), but you can [try searching for others](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins).

Comment: I just stumbled across a FOSS PDF embed JavaScript library, [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/). That could be added to your theme then use a `raw` directive to display it.

Comment: "Added to your theme" means modify your Sphinx theme's templates. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html